# inserting new tags with class names in Javascript innerText?

Tags: javascript

I made a forEach case for text loop,
and this moment, I;m facing a problem that I cannot put span tag in return result of innerText.

```
data.forEach(item => {
  const dataTitle = document.createElement('p');
  dataTitle.innerText = data.title + '<span class="p-90">' + data.subTitle + '</span>'
  viewContainer.appendChild(dataTitle);
});
```

this is my code, but the < span class =".... is exposed to the site in raw.
how can I fix it?

Comment: to parse and add some new attributes you should use `.innerHTML` component API function instead of `innerText`

Comment: Use `const dataSubtitle = document.createElement('span')`, append it to the `dataTitle`, set its class and text content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. use innerHTML instead of innerText and replace data.title with item.title. same for data.subTitle.

```
data.forEach((item) => {
      const dataTitle = document.createElement("p");
      dataTitle.innerHTML =
        item.title + '<span class="p-90">' + item.subTitle + "</span>";
        viewContainer.appendChild(dataTitle);
    });
```

Comment: But then don't forget to html-escape the title and subtitle.